# Load chatroom .html document from specific line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically my question is: how would I load a .html document from a specific line? Basically the .html document is a chatroom and is loaded using JavaScript. Now what I want it to do is to load the document from after a specific line. So for example when the user enters the chatroom this line is posted into the text document:

```
$username Entered the room.
```

How would I load the document from after this line so any messages sent before the user entering the room would not show up?

Below is how I load and refresh the chatroom. How can I get it to load from after this line has been posted?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.get('/account/broadcast/uploads/<? echo $row['username'];?>/<? echo $row['username'];?>.html', 
        function(data) {
            $("#chathistory1").html(newdata);
        });
    }, 2000);
});</script>
```

This is the exact code that gets posted into the chatroom when a user enters the room:

```
<font><strong><font color="$usercolor">$username</font>  has entered the room.</strong></font>
```

Comment: every message is in a new line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose what you are looking is getting the last line of the chat room try this:

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            $.get('/account/broadcast/uploads/<? echo $row['username'];?>/<? echo $row['username'];?>.html', 
            function(data) {
                var newdata=data.substr(data.lastIndexOf("\n")+1);
                $("#chathistory1").html(newdata);
            });
        }, 2000);
    });</script>
```

Comment: This code would do the job if all the lines were seperated I should have mentioned that the chatroom is just one long line aha, I dont make it easy for myself do I ahah xD Thnkyou though, this still loads all the previous messages. +1 What I think I will do is alter the way I post to the chatroom and then I can use this instead of loading it the way I was thinking I will mark this as the answer thankyou for the help!

Comment: Welcome, if you need anything more, always glad to help )